# MATLAB function to get svn repo rev#

Tags: matlab, batch-file, svn

I want to query a subversion repository for its revision # from within a MATLAB program (.m file), so I can include it in an output file I'm generating. I need to be able to do this programmatically, so no GUI tools that require point and click to retrieve the info.

I'm thinking I'll just create a batch file like this

```
@echo OFF
svn info --show-item revision [url]
```

and call the batch file from the MATLAB program with the [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command.

Are there other ways to accomplish this task? How do they compare with my idea?

Comment: Anything wrong or to improve with your current solution?

Comment: @Daniel, it would be nice to have it all in code, instead of having to do a (platform-dependent) system call. But it's not that big a deal, and I definitely don't want to require installing any software.

Answer (score 1):

There is a GUI you can download from Mathworks:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23508-subversion-gui

but honestly, I would just do what you said - write a system call to the native svn.

Comment: The GUI uses system commands anyway: `eval(['[ status, err ] = system( sprintf(''svn commit ',regexprep(fullfile(handles.root,topDirList{dirNum}),'\\','\\\\'),' -m "',msg ,'"''',newLines,') );' ] );` eek...

Comment: It has to be automate-able. It's going to be a build step in the generation of a generated file. GUI doesn't work well for that.

Comment: DO NOT DOWNVOTE this answer on account of the GUI - I edited my question with that part after this answer was posted.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve platform independent code, you could switch to [svnkit](http://svnkit.com/) which can be directly used in MATLAB code using [the java bridge](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html?refresh=true).

Comment: Would either of these tools require a separate installation step on the machine that runs the program? I want to avoid that.

Comment: The java bridge is part of every Matlab installation and svnkit is just a java library you need to copy.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be just the sort of thing I was asking for. Although I've already implemented the solution in the question, and it may be good enough, but I will keep this in my back pocket.